# Можно ли использовать куки, чтобы потом не вводить капчу?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

**ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ:** С#, WebDriver (при необходимости)

Хочу написать парсер, который будет скачивать информацию программно (без браузера).
Но у некоторых сайтов бывает навароченная капча.

Чтобы не возится с проходом капчи программно, можно ли реализовать следующий сценарий?

**СЦЕНАРИЙ:**

1. Заходим на сайт через браузер (либо штатным браузером C# или с использованием WebDriver );
2. Проходим капчу в ручную;
3. Копируем куки;
4. Далее программой начинаем парсить.      Запросы для парсинга отправляются с ранее сформированными куки.

**ВОПРОС**
    1. Возможно ли реализовать данный сценарий?

**PS**
Только осваиваю, поэтому могут быть неточности в формулировке вопроса и терминологии.

Comment: краткий ответ - да. Но могут  быть проблемы. Например, сайт проверяет по куке браузер/айпи и тому подобное.

Comment: @KoVadim Если не сложно, не могли бы вы привести пример для internet explorer. Т.е. через internet explorer залогинился на ru.stackoverflow.com. Как кодом взять куки моего входа через internet explorer и войти на любую страницу ru.stackoverflow.com и далее спарсить страницу? Если я правильно понимаю этот процесс. Куки находятся здесь c:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\.  Проводник C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Comment: я не пишу на шарпе.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно.
Но в твоем случае лучше пойти другим путем, а именно:

1. Создать отдельный профиль браузера
2. Использовать его при инициализации селениума.

Это позволит тебе не мучится с запоминанием кук через костыли вроде сейва кук в XML или сериализации. Все нужные данные уже будут внутри профиля браузера.

Важно: Я НЕ советую использовать IE если это возможно. Селениум с ним работает просто отвратно.